# Python: Regex to find associated HTML links

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need some help writing a regex pattern which can find affiliated links from a webpage.

#### Example code:

```
import requests,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://www.example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

# example_of_affiliate_links = ['http://example.com/click/click?p=1&t=url&s=IDHERE&url=https://www.mywebsite.com/920&f=TXL&name=electronic/ps4/','https://example.net/click/camref:IDhere/destination:https://www.mywebsite.com/product/138/sony-ps4.html']
```

I want to collect all affiliated links for "mywebsite.com", using the following regex pattern, but it is not capturing any links.

`pattern = re.compile(r'([http,https]://www.mywebsite.com\S[\.html,\.php,\&]$)')`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Here is a [site I use regularly](https://regexr.com/) to build / test regex patterns.

Comment: [This one](https://ihateregex.io/playground#) is also pretty cool to have visual representations of your regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the regex you're looking for:

```
https?://www.mywebsite.com\S*$
```

#### What's wrong with your regex?

```
([http,https]://www.mywebsite.com\S[\.html,\.php,\&]$)
```

- The braces on each sides are useless
- `[]` means **any of those characters**, so in `[http,https]`, you're looking of one character, which might be "`h`", "`t`", "`t`", "`p`", "`s`" or "`,`"
- `\S` only captures one character, your need to add a multiplier after it
- Same thing goes for the `[\.html,\.php,\&]` part

Comment: this fails on http://example.com/click/click?p=1&t=url&s=IDHERE&url=https://www.mywebsite.com/920&f=TXL&name=electronic/ps4/

Comment: this fails if any parameters are placed after .html eg `https://example.net/click/camref:IDhere/destination:https://www.mywebsite.com/product/138/sony-ps4.html&q=ps4`